# How to forward image to another chat with telegram bot python api?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

User sends image to telegram bot.
Is it possible to forward image or send it to another chat without saving?

my code

```
def reg_text(message):
global text
text = message.text
if len(text.split()) < 2:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Too short message.")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_text)

else:
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Perfect! Send an image")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, reg_photo)
```

def reg_photo(message):
#get image id and send it to another chat (which is constant)

Comment: Please read how to ask questions on SO and post your code which you've tried.

Comment: @GaganTK I've edited my question. There is a code which I have at the moment

Comment: OK I see the code now. How are you reading the image sent from user? Where is that in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working bot and among many features, one is exactly what you want to achieve. This `def` works identifying if a **image** or a **document** was sent by the user. If it's a document (**if** part of the loop), the bot send the document to a channel on Telegram; if it's a image (**else** part of the loop), the bot send the image to the same channel.

```
def file_handler (update, context):

    if update.message['photo'] == []:
        fileID = update.message['document']['file_id']
        fileName = update.message['document']['file_name']
        context.bot.sendDocument(chat_id = channel_chat_id,
                                 caption = 'image caption',
                                 document = fileID)

    else:
        fileID = update.message['photo'][-1]['file_id']
        context.bot.sendPhoto(chat_id = channel_chat_id,
                              caption = 'image caption',
                              photo = fileID)
```

Remembering that on `def main()` you must have a MessageHandler to handle `def file_handler`.

```
dp = updater.dispatcher
dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.document | Filters.photo, file_handler))
```

Let me know if this works for you!